# What does AppStore App file size mean?

Tags: app-store, itunes, filesize

It says that the limit of download from the AppStore over-the-air is only 50 MB. But we have this app for some reason it exceeds 50+ MB. The previous version is only 49.1 MB then we just added about 100 kB but when we shipped it, and got released it became 51.5 MB.

We didn't receive any warning about file size, and we can also download it via 3G.

Now, my question is, what is that file size really mean? Is it the file size of the package or when it is installed? See image below.

[image: file size]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the package file. Apple may modify it between you submitting it and it going on to the app store (DRM, for example).

I recommend keeping the apps under about 45MB at submit time. That way, you'll be pretty confident that the overheads Apple may introduce in the process will not push it over the 50MB limit.

Also, it may be that Apple are using a different conversion (perhaps 1000KB = 1MB, instead of 1024KB = 1MB) in certain areas, which could account for this.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Another thing, it says that the limit is 50 MB and our app is 51.5 MB, how is it possible to download that over-the-air using 3G or 4G?